# Start creating a basic client-server communication

Tags: java, html, web-services, rest

I'm trying to figure out how to start a basic client-server communication.
the client is the browser showing some HTML files.
lets assume that the server is a plain java service exposed by a rest API.

So my idea was to save all static HTML pages (and scripts) on the server and add an API which send a specific file on demand. then, the client will trigger some other requests triggered by the HTML page that was loaded to the browser.

I came out with the following method to do that :

```
    @Get
    @Path(/static-resource/{path:.*}
    public Response readStaticResource(String path){
       final String fullPath = "fullResourceDir/path";
       StreamingOutput streamingOutput = new StreamingOutput(){
           public void write(OutputStream output) throws IOException, WebApplicationException{
                InputStream resourceAsStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resourcePath);
                IOUtils.copy(resourceAsStream, output);
           }
       }; 
       return Response.ok(streamingOutput).build();
}
```

So my questions are as follow :

1. Does all of that sound reasonable? I might be completely wrong. How does it usually be done?
2. Where does the HTML pages should be located? It's looks a little bit weird to me that the client/server should build the full path where those HTML files are be saved. as you can see in the code, the full path is added to the path given by the client. In addition the static-resource which is part of the address also looks a bit strange.

Comment: I am not sure I understand correctly. But, you can use javascript or php to make REST API Calls to your server. Your REST API call than will return 'certain' dynamic content that you can display in your HTML pages.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that it is a java REST API (may be jersey). What you are trying to achieve is very naive approach to serve HTML files. You can go for Servlets or frameworks like Spring MVC which will have end-points and server views(HTML).

> Look into the following documentations [spring-mvc](http://www.javatpoint.com/spring-3-mvc-tutorial) [spring.io](https://spring.io/docs)
>   [servlets](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/)